# SQL Profiler - no hostname on Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, hostname, sql-server-profiler

I am currently using SQL Server 2008 and Crystal Report 8.0. There are times when I need to know what computer runs the crystal report and unfortunately I can't seem to see it in SQL Profiler.

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution to this? or did one of the below answers work for you?

Comment: Yep. Changed server type from Microsoft SQL Server to OLE DB for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `HostName` column in SQL Profiler, and it does indeed show the computer name which ran it, for crystal reports as well. The event that best captures a completed Crystal Report is `TSQL -> SQL:Batch Completed`.

Alternatively, each user can be logging into the crystal report's database with their own username (we use Active Directory), and the username shows under the `LoginName` column.  Generally bad practice to have everyone knowing an admin level or even `sa` password..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your are already seeing the Host Name column in SQL Profiler.

Then make your computers using OLE DB (ADO) for connections. When you configure a datasource you can configure advanced properties. Add there a property named: ***Workstation ID*** As the value set the name of the computer or whatever you need. Then you will see the hostname in SQL Profiler.

Here is a list what you can set additionally: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx

[image: Crystal Reports OLE DB ADO Advanced Connection Properties]